# Refinement of an infinite chain

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

This might sound like a very trivial question.
Given an infinite chain of subsets indexed by ordinals $\lambda \leq \mu$:

$$X_\mu\subseteq ...\subseteq X_\lambda\subseteq...X_1\subseteq X_0$$
where $\mu$ is any ordinal.

Is it possible to get a refinement where all the inclusions are strict (where only the repeated subsets are gone)?

This is, is it possible to get a second chain
$$X_{\mu'}\subsetneq ...\subsetneq X_{\lambda'}\subsetneq...X_1\subsetneq X_0$$
where for any $X_i$ in the first chain there exists a  $X_{i'}$ in the second chain where $X_i=X_{i'}$?

I know that $\mu'$ will be smaller than $\mu$, and that even the cardinal of $\mu$ and $\mu'$ might be different.

My way to do this is the following.
I start with $X_0$ if $X_0=X_1$ then I remove $X_1$. If $X_0=X_2$ then I remove $X_2$ and so on. If $X_1\not= X_\lambda$ for some $\lambda$ then I move to $\lambda$ and start again the process. I believe that this works because all the indexes are ordinals and thus have a successor. But I am not very confident working with infinite chains and I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: If you are familiar with transfinite recursion that is the right way to go. Also since you are working with ordinals which are well ordered you don't have to use choice!

Comment: Okay, so the idea is to do what I was suggesting but using  transfinite recursion, right?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but it seems your question is missing the assumption that $X_\mu\neq X_0$?

Comment: @Couchy: Not missing. In that case $X_0$ is the chain.

Comment: just thought of this. Using the replacement axiom create a set that contains all of the $X_\alpha$ this will "eliminate any duplicates". Then you are basically done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don’t care about the subscripts, just let $\mathscr{X}=\{X_\xi:\xi\le\mu\}$; then $\left\langle\mathscr{X},\supsetneqq\right\rangle$ is a well-ordered chain that contains exactly one representative of each set in the original chain.

If you want to extract a specific subsequence of $\left\langle X_\xi:\xi\le\mu\right\}$ that contains exactly one representative of each set, let

$$\varphi:\mu+1\to\mu+1:\xi\mapsto\min\left\{\eta\le\xi:X_\eta=X_\xi\right\}\,;$$

then $\left\langle X_\xi:\xi\in\operatorname{ran}\varphi\right\rangle$ is a subsequence of $\left\langle X_\xi:\xi\le\mu\right\}$ that contains exactly one representative of each set. If you want nicer indexing, you can let $\nu$ be the order type of $\operatorname{ran}\varphi$ and $h:\nu\to\operatorname{ran}\varphi$ the associated order-isomorphism and write

$$\left\langle X_\xi:\xi\in\operatorname{ran}\varphi\right\rangle=\left\langle X_{h(\xi)}:\xi<\nu\right\rangle\,.$$